# pywinauto/examples/uninstall_7zip.py doesn't work on Windows 10

Tags: pywinauto

Has anyone ported "pywinauto/examples/uninstall_7zip.py" example to windows 10? I tried to run it, but it fails:

```
NewWindow.type_keys(r'Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features{ENTER}', with_spaces=True, 
set_foreground=False)  (Fails in this line)
```

I modified to reach the control panel uninstall window, further nor able to get / select the 7-Zip program. Below is the code snippet to reach uninstall window:

```
Application().start('control.exe')
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='explorer.exe', title='Control Panel')

# Go to "Programs"
app.window(title='Control Panel').ProgramsHyperlink.invoke()
app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=30, usage_interval=1.0)

# Go to "Uninstall a program"
app.window(title='Programs').child_window(title='Uninstall a program', 
control_type='Hyperlink').invoke()
app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=30, usage_interval=1.0)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work" and "fails".

Comment: if you  try to run the 7-zip program on windows 10, it fails because of below resons -

Comment: Because of what reasons?

Comment: Below code fails with "No items match your search"  ==> try:
    NewWindow.AddressBandRoot.click_input()
    NewWindow.type_keys(r'Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features{ENTER}',  with_spaces=True, set_foreground=False)

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica, I modified the code and I'm able to reach uninstall window, but unable to select the program to uninstall, below is the modified program -

Comment: Getting error at this line - item_7z = ProgramsAndFeatures.FolderView.get_item('7-Zip')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated program to uninstall 7-zip program from control panel -

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto import Desktop
import time

Application().start('control.exe')
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='explorer.exe', title='Control 
Panel')

# Go to "Programs"
app.window(title='Control Panel').ProgramsHyperlink.invoke()
app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=30, usage_interval=1.0)

# Go to "Uninstall a program"
app.window(title='Programs').child_window(title='Uninstall a program', 
control_type='Hyperlink').invoke()
app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=30, usage_interval=1.0)


NewWindow = app.window(top_level_only=True, active_only=True, 
class_name='CabinetWClass')

NewWindow.type_keys(r'7-Zip{ENTER}', with_spaces=True, set_foreground=False)
time.sleep(10)
```

After this I'm unable to figure out how to transfer control to the resulting window, and click the 'Next' button.
so mixed pyautogui commands, as the uninstall windows is active, it's receiving the keyboard key press
     `pyautogui.press('enter')  => repeat this 3 times to click Next on all windows`

Comment: @Vasily Ryabov, need your help